# Pull to refresh in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement pull to refresh in my table view app. I've been looking around at people's examples and I've gathered that this is pretty much the gist of it:

```
var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!  

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
{
 // Code to refresh table view  
}
```

However the only examples I can find are from a while ago and I know the language has changed a lot since then! When I try to use the code above, I get the following error next to my declaration of refreshControl:

```
Cannot override with a stored property 'refresh control'
```

My first thought before reading other examples is that I would have to declare the variable like so:

```
var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

Like I did with some other variables but I guess not. 
Any ideas what the issue is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gather your class inherits `UITableViewController`.  `UITableViewController` already declares the `refreshControl` property like this:

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?
```

You don't need to override it.  Just get rid of your `var` declaration and assign to the inherited property.

Since the inherited property is `Optional`, you need to use a `?` or `!` to unwrap it:

```
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware refreshControl is already declared! I appreciate your help. However now when I pull down to refresh, the app crashes with:
`terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` where should the try catch go?

Comment: What is the full message?

Comment: The full message reads: `[SimpleText.TimelineTableViewController loadData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d5cfd0
2014-09-30 15:25:26.983 SimpleText[2639:472743] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'`

Comment: You didn't post any code that sends a `loadData:` message, and that is a separate issue from your `refreshControl` compiler error.

Comment: Sorry thats my mistake, I changed the name of refresh: to loadData: , I forgot to mention that haha

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code in viewDidLoad

```
self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        self.refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
 self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)
```

Works Fine :)